# SQL - Difference between values between dates using Guids

Tags: sql, date, guid, between

I have a table like:

[date], [guid], [value (int)]

Data looks like:

```
10/1, id1, 10
10/1, id2, 5
10/2, id1, 12
10/2, id2, 14
10/3, id1, 11
```

I want to return:

```
10/1, id1, 2
10/1, id2, 9
10/2, id1, -1
```

The same ID's match, grabbing the next day (Not the next date) value, using the past value, subtracting.

So 10/1, id1, 2 is received via

```
10/1, id1, 10
10/2, id1, 12
```

So we return the first day, 10/1, and the id, id1, and the value of 12-10 = 2.

How would I do this via SQL?

Thanks!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Date diff is always 1 or just the next date for each id?

Comment: In case of SqlServer please also include year 2008, 2012, 2014

Comment: You're saying id1 and id2 are GUID's.  Do we also have a key identity field so we can tell which was created when?  This would be a simple SUM with a GROUP BY[date], [guid] if the [value field] was stored as a negative number for the second entry for a given day.  Without that, we're going to need to build logic to determine which one should have the sign flipped.  In your example, look at: 
`10/1, id1, 10` and 
`10/1, id1, 12`
which is supposed to net to a summary line of 
`10/1, id1, 2`
How are we knowing it should be `12-10 = 2` and not `10-12 = -2` without order?

Comment: Year: 2012, 11.0.5343   
  
No Key Identity.

MS SQL Server

Comment: @JustinWarner Still waiting for my answer to Date diff is always 1 or just the next date for each id?

Answer (score 0):

Untested.
get all values from t1 join to a coorlated subquery whose sole purpose is to find the next minimum date for each guid that is higher than the date on that guid. Then join to set of whole values again and limit to only that guid and min date identified, use this t3 value to subtract from the initial t1 set values.

```
SELECT t1.date, t1.guid, t3.value-t1.value
FROM tableName t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT min(t2.Date) minDate, t2.GUID 
            FROM TableName t2
            WHERE t2.Date> t1.date  
            GROUP BY t2.GUID ) B
 on B.GUID = t1.guid
INNER JOIN tableName t3
 on t3.GUID= T1.guid
and t3.date = b.mindate
```

Assumption made here is that guid and date are UNIQUE pair, non-duplicated for all records.

Answer (score 0):

Here one more based of what has been given by you. This may be what you are looking at

```
declare @test table 
(
    dateId date,
    gguid uniqueidentifier,
    value int 
)

insert into @test(dateId,gguid,value)
Values('10/1/2015','1DFE73AF-7940-4CDC-A22F-92DA8DEF7B6E', 10),
('10/1/2015', '6A057D92-7279-4E34-8ADC-870E45B5D49A', 5),
('10/2/2015', '1DFE73AF-7940-4CDC-A22F-92DA8DEF7B6E', 12),
('10/2/2015', '6A057D92-7279-4E34-8ADC-870E45B5D49A', 14),
('10/3/2015', '1DFE73AF-7940-4CDC-A22F-92DA8DEF7B6E', 11);

with test
as
(
select dateId,gguid,value 
,RANK() over (partition by gguid order by dateId) as RNK
from @test
) select T.dateId,T.gguid,T.value, IsNull(T.value-X.value,0) as lastday  from test T left join (select dateId,gguid,value, RNK+1 as RNK from test)  AS X
on  X.gguid = t.gguid and T.RNK = X.RNK
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [**LAG()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx)

**[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9df91e/3)**

```
SELECT [Date], [guid], [value],  
       LAG([value],1, null) OVER (PARTITION BY [guid] ORDER BY [Date]) as previousValue
FROM Table1
```

**OUTPUT**

Ignore rows where `PreviousValue IS NULL` and then calculate `Value - PreviousValue`

```
|       Date | guid | value | previousValue |
|------------|------|-------|---------------|
| 2001-10-01 |  id1 |    10 |        (null) |
| 2001-10-02 |  id1 |    12 |            10 |
| 2001-10-03 |  id1 |    11 |            12 |
| 2001-10-01 |  id2 |     5 |        (null) |
| 2001-10-02 |  id2 |    14 |             5 |
```

Wraping all together

```
SELECT [Date], [guid], [value] - previousValue as [value]
FROM (
  SELECT [Date], [guid], [value],  
         LAG([value],1, null) OVER (PARTITION BY [guid] ORDER BY [Date]) as previousValue
  FROM Table1
) T
WHERE T.previousValue IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY [Date], [guid]
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2012+, you would use `lead()`.

If you wanted all five rows, you would do:

```
select d.*, lead(value) over (partition by id order by date) as next_value
from data d;
```

For your particular output, you need a subquery:

```
select d.id, d.date, d.next_value
from (select d.*, lead(value) over (partition by id order by date) as next_value
      from data d
     ) d
where next_value is not null;
```